# Skype4Py WAV input

Tags: python, audio, skype, skype4py

Thanks so much for taking your time to help me with this problem.

There seems to be an error in the Skype4py module InputDevice. It doesn't allow you to input any WAV files. Could one of you more advanced programmers take a look at it. I will be checking this page for updates and answering any questions you have regarding this issue.

https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/14
https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/15

Thanks so much for your time,

Rhyno

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: I'm trying to play a wav file through Skype.

Comment: Excuse me for not answering, I was tired and somehow didn't comprehend the other questions. I expected it to play the WAV file, but it didn't. Hope that clears some stuff up.

Comment: Please read technical answer from here https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/15#issuecomment-18950089